# When is it proper to use 托您的福?

Tags: meaning

I think it means that I succeeded in part because of your luck.

I've heard this used when I was in Beijing a few times.

Comment: More close to because of your blessing, I think

Comment: I suspect that this comes from Japanese "おかけさまで". I don't recall hearing it a lot in China. It may appear more in a translation of Japanese work (movie, novel, etc).

Comment: Why Japanese? What's that mean in Japanese?

Comment: @DavidFaux The same meaning. This maybe an misunderstanding, just a wild guess.

Comment: I hear "托您的福" more often as a sarcastic comment. A: 你今天没去看电影？You didn't go to the movies today? B: 托你的福，我帮你找钥匙找了半个小时，没来及去电影院。(Sarcastically) 托你的福! I spent half an hour looking for your key and missed the movie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite common in chinese. The English equivalent of this phrase should be "thanks to you/your..".
托 means because of, a variant of this phrase can be 托您洪福, 托您的洪福..

Comment: Fivesheep, I know your answer has been accepted, but can you expand it a bit? Thank you. :)

Comment: I think 托 translated to "rely on" is more precise here. 托 as in 依托 depends on. so 托你的福 -> relying on your 福.  福 as in 福气, means 'good fortune'. Chinese believes that 福 is a kind of positive energy, anyone round some with 福 will take some advantage of it.

Comment: Thanks, consider including that in your answer so it's more visible. :)

Comment: pls use w/ caution. depending on the situation, it can sound quite sarcastic...bcz it's overly polite...rule of thumb is not to use it unless the recipient is 100 years old :) a modern day equivalent would be "在您的帮助下，。。。"

Comment: additional info to my above comment: 1) if you are using 托您的洪福 to mean 'thanks to your help', then my above modern day equivalent is correct; but 2) if you are using it to mean 'thanks to the good fortune that you've brought me', then there really is no modern day equivalent that i can think of off the top of my head.